# Auto-Complete Box with Search Bar comes up empty but there are arrays Mapped (React)

Tags: json

```js
[
    {
      "id": "619a92649f699a480b890032",
      "eth": "Dominican",
      "gen": "male",
      "iden": "gay",
      "title": "Excepteur exercitation laborum non do consequat.",
      "about": "Exercitation est ipsum do est cillum fugiat nostrud nisi.",
      "img": "../public/img/test_img.jpg",
      "char": 2,
      "set": "Beechmont",
      "firstN": "Hayden",
      "lastN": "Trujillo",
      "email": "velit@gmail.com",
      "bio": "Nostrud in adipisicing laborum. Excepteur culpa sint sint dolor laboris aute. Nisi minim veniam veniam consectetur est pariatur cupidatat. Laboris reprehenderit minim adipisicing et non. Est nostrud consequat reprehenderit aute et tempor enim. Velit cillum et aliquip. Non ea reprehenderit pariatur aliqua fugiat minim velit."
    },
    */etc... about 100 entries/*
```

I feel like I have drowned in this code. Need a pair of eyes that aren't mine to help me figure out where I am stuck or areas that I just missed completely. So to start off, I am building a database app for my own Non-Profit. We will commission playwrights to write scenes and monologues for young latinx students. I am creating a development app as a proof of concept. Won a grant for the development of this and other things in our org. I figured out pretty quickly that without a debounce NoSQL DBS can get pretty expensive. So I am using JSON data to simulate a backend. Currently, I have the search bar working well with an onKeyPress(Enter) to do a query and render cards from the search. What I am stuck on is rendering `</li />`s
for the suggestion box. I am now currently working to use a component `<Suggestion/>` to render out possible searches based on three keyword value/pairs (eth, iden, gen) from the JSON. It would like for the searchbox to display the eth.value || iden.value || gen.value then setSearch to that value so that when I hit enter or click on the rendered `<li>` the `<RenderGrid />` will mount. Also I'm self taught so I'm learning as I go. That's why its in a Redux framework with only one state being tied with a reducer. I will eventually practice more with it once I learn how to make it work first.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import RenderGrid from './RenderGrid'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'
import { Header } from "./Header";
import { Footer } from "./Footer";


const Main = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
    const [results, setResults] = useState([])
    const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState()
    const [sugg, setSugg] = useState([])
    const data = useSelector(state => state.data)
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const createData = () => {
            setDefaultData(data)
        }
        return createData()
    }, [data])  
   

    

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <div>
                <SearchBar placeholder="What do you identify as?" search={search} setSearch={setSearch} setResults={setResults} defaultData={defaultData} sugg={sugg} setSugg={setSugg} />
            </div>
            <RenderGrid results={results} />                
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
    
    
}
export default Main
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Suggestion from "./Suggestion";
import { BiSearchAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import { RiCloseCircleLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const SearchBar = ({placeholder,search,setResults,setSearch,defaultData, sugg, setSugg}) => {

  const querySuggestion = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
    if (search.length > 0) {
      const filteredSugg = defaultData.filter((data) => {
        return (
          data.eth.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          data.gen.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          data.iden.toLowerCase().includes(search)
        )
      })
      setSugg(filteredSugg)
    }
  }

  const queryJson = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter"){
      const filteredSearch = defaultData.filter((data) => {
      return (
          data.eth.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          data.gen.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          data.iden.toLowerCase().includes(search)
      )
    })
    setResults(filteredSearch);
  }}
  
  const clearInput = () => {
    setResults([])
    setSearch("")
    setSugg([])
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="search-input">
        
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={search}
            onChange={querySuggestion}
            onKeyPress={queryJson}
          />
          <div className="autocom-box">
            <Suggestion search={search} sugg={sugg} />
          </div>

          <div className="searchIcon">
            {search.length > 0 ? (
              <RiCloseCircleLine
                icon="fa-solid fa-times-circle"
                className="icon"
                onClick={clearInput}
              />
            ) : (
              <BiSearchAlt 
              icon="fa-solid fa-search"
              className="icon" />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
export default SearchBar;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import { Card, 
  CardImg, 
  CardBody, 
  CardTitle, 
  CardText} from "reactstrap"

const RenderGrid = ({results}) => {
  const cardArray = results.map(card => (
    <Card className="col-12 col-sm-5 p-sm-1 col-lg-3 p-md-2 m-1" key={card.id}>
      <CardImg variant="top" src="/img/test_img.jpg" />
      <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>
              <h3>{`Title:
              ${card.title}`}</h3>
          </CardTitle>
          <CardText>
              {`Summary:
              ${card.about}`}
          </CardText>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  ))
  // console.log("In RenderGrid passing cardarray")
  // console.log(cardArray)

  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
        {cardArray}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RenderGrid;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

const Suggestion = ({search, sugg}) => {

    const suggestionArray = sugg.map(arr => (
        <div key={arr.id}>
            <li className="col-12">{arr.eth}</li>
        </div>
    ))
    

    useEffect(() => {
        const querySugg = () => {
        if (search.length > 0) {
            console.log("QuerySugg fired!!")
            
        }
    }
        querySugg()
    },[search])

    

    

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {suggestionArray}
            </div>
        </div> 
    )
}
export default Suggestion
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you could also post your sample data (JSON).

Comment: Ok added. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good UX to change the search box value when one of the suggestions is clicked. From what I see the user can search by gender identity, but you show etnicity in the suggestion field. I'd rather show there the names, and they can search as you have it by any of the 3 criteria. I think the proper solution would use redux, but I don't see the code where you set up the redux store, so I simply added a "callback" property to `<Suggestion>`. You can see how it works on [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-lake-eur80?file=/src/Suggestion.js)

Comment: Thanks this puts me into the right direction on how to solve this for myself. So I have attatched my configstore and my only reducer. So you are saying I should create a reducer that dispatches when the value in the search bar gets triggered from the event of typing in it? I can create an action that updates suggestions and use the suggestions component to read out my searched items. 

So for example lets say I start typing "m", I could have Male pop up on the auto or Mexican pop up?